# Increase drawing speed of SurfaceView

Tags: java, android, surfaceview

Here is my project: I want to print a graphic with the data that I receive from the USB port.

I'm currently using a `SurfaceView` but I just noticed that it will pass through the thread 30 times per second, but I would like to do it 10 times faster.

```
public void run() {
    while (isItOK) {
        if (!holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
            continue;
        }
        Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();
        c.drawPoint(pos, 50, p);
        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to increase the speed or I have to use the `GLSurfaceView` or by another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call `unlockCanvasAndPost()`, you're flipping buffers, sending the buffer you just drew off to the system graphics compositor (SurfaceFlinger).  If the dots you're drawing seem to flicker, it's because SurfaceView is double- or triple-buffered.

SurfaceFlinger doesn't drop frames from SurfaceView, so if you send them faster than the device can display them, the buffer queue will fill up and block.  A new buffer is displayed with every display refresh, which typically happens 60x per second.  So if you draw in a tight loop, you will not exceed 60fps.

If you're receiving 300 samples per second, a better way to structure your program is to receive data as quickly as possible, and draw the current set after each screen refresh.  You can get a callback from the display through the [Choreographer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Choreographer.html) class.

Comment: thanks for the answer.
If i understood, i reached the speed of the 30 frames per second because the thread will print a point in the first buffer and print nothing in the second buffer and if i want 60 frames per second i have to create 2 canvas and call them one after another ?

Comment: No... see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Double_buffering_in_computer_graphics for an explanation of double-buffering. I don't know why you hit 30fps rather than 60fps. I can guarantee you won't hit 300fps while you're synchronized to the display.